# How to plot stacked time-series in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

I have 5 high-frequency time series, with new observations arriving each 5 seconds. Each of the time-series has values that vary between -1.0 and 1.0. I want to plot them stacked up on top of each other in React, perhaps like either of the below graphs. I want to view these time-series evolve in real time. I also want to be able to render it over historical data.

The purpose is to monitor telemetry, where I'm interested in both the cumulative sum of the 5 time-series, as well as each individual value.

How can I do this in React?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic on SO, see the guidance in the [help].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I changed the question so it wasn't a library recommendation. I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: It's generally better to start from what you've tried, and what the specific problem you currently have is.